# Nested Loops with Rename

Tags: batch-rename

I have problems with nested loops and renaming in a batch-script maybe can help me please with this. Every single loop is working but when I want to put them together I am a little bit screwed :-)

The first loop is going throw an array, to be more flexible with name-changing.

The second loop is pointing to a folder and rename all PNGs underneath, also in sub folders, with the array variables from the first loop.

Thank in advance for any hints!

```
@ECHO OFF    

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: rename array variables

SET RPATT[1]=a    
SET RPATT[2]=b    

:: replace variables    

SET REPLACE=_

FOR /L %%P IN (1,1,2) DO (    
SET UPATT=!RPATT[%%P]!    
ECHO LOOP1    
ECHO !UPATT!    
PAUSE    
FOR /R "D:\test\" %%R IN (*.png) DO (    
SET "FILE=%%~nxR"    
ECHO LOOP2    
ECHO !UPATT!    
PAUSE    
REN "%%R" "!FILE:%UPATT%=%REPLACE%!"    
)    
)
```

Comment: Ever thought of use a different thing like Perl instead of using such a head-banger?

Comment: Hi – I have no experience with Pearl and in this case it’s just a small part of my still created batch file.

Comment: Was just an idea. People doing system stuff often use tools given first hand though in the backyard there were plenty of professional tools for free ;-)